# Python String Literal Inside Popen command

Tags: python, string, popen, literals

I am trying to pass a string literal to a Popen command, but it is isn't working:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/festival', '-b', '(SayText "%s")']) % text
```

The idea is that I want to pass text into the Popen command, which calls the program festival, which will read the input text.

Is it possible to pass a string literal inside a popen command? My guess is that this isn't working because the Popen commands are in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, format the list element, and not the result of `Popen` or the argument list:

```
festivalCmd = '(SayText "%s")' % text.replace('"', '')
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/festival', '-b', festivalCmd])
```

The call to [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) ensures that you're correctly handing inputs like `foo"bar` without failing.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, for a list.. but to use a much simpler example.  https://gist.github.com/gartha1/29ac8d4431f0bb019ef017e467d01e67   now look at the output from wmic or task manager, re the command line  
 https://gist.github.com/gartha1/eae1a16d55950fc5312ed01a461191bf   `c:\windows\system32\calc.exe "--profile-directory=\"Profile 3\""`  Or if I try to use the example you do..  https://gist.github.com/gartha1/9d70278a278a8840cf14908ef5600572  it still doesn' tpass literal quotes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. I don't know much about festival speech synth system but if you wrote it like this, that would be work:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/festival', '-b', '(SayText "%s")' % text])
```